# In MOSS 2007, how to sort a list by a total/aggregate?

Tags: 2007, list, list-view, groups, sorting

I have a basic issue tracking list with a few columns, let's say **Application**, **Title**, **Created By**, and **Task Priority**.

My list is grouped by **Application** and I am performing a Total (Average) on **Task Priority**, so the view with some data looks like:

**Title**                                                         **Created By**        **Task Priority**

---

**Example Application**                                               **Average = 5.0**

1. Fix bug when user logs in                           pandincus            3.0
2. Why are there duplicate people?                pandincus            7.0

**Other Application**                                                    **Average = 1.5**

1. Runs slow at 3:00 PM daily                         pandincus            1.0
2. Add new column for vacation days             pandincus            2.0

The above works fine. However, I'd like to be able to sort by the average task priority. Currently, I cannot find any way to do this, since the 'group' sorting takes precedence.

Is it possible, either using the SharePoint site or by using SharePoint Designer, to sort the groups based on the average task priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert that view to a data view web part in Sharepoint Designer, you can build your own sorting logic and you should be able to sort by the nodeset average.

Comment: Anyone knows how to do this in Sharepoint Designer 2010?

Comment: Nodeset doesn't seem to be available for sorting in SPD 2010. This answer needs more elaboration to be helpful.